# You can tap through the X meant to close the achievements view

Tags: bug, android-app, achievements-dialog

If I click to open achievements from a question when I click the X to close the achievements view I end up on the answers tab of the question, I assume because the X is over the tab and it's tapping through.

---

It appears if I hit the X it's ok, but if I tap anywhere else in the top row (where the X is) then I can switch to the question or answer tab.

Comment: I've just been able to do the same with the feed in the background so it's not only the questions view that has this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this isn't an issue anymore (for me at least on my Nexus 5).