# Android app crash bug, clicking comment under achievements view

Tags: bug, android-app

I haven't quite been able to put my finger on this bug. What I've observed is that if the achievements view is expanded the app very often crashes if I "miss" when trying to push the button to close the view and instead touch some portion of the view with no active components. It also seems that touches in that general vicinity are interpreted as being meant for the views beneath the achievements view, because I've noticed that sometimes I end up clicking buttons in the question I was looking at at the time that are behind the achievements view.

I'm using the beta version of the app on a Samsung galaxy S4. The OS version is 4.4.2.

Edit: I've been able to reproduce it consistently. It happens when the click beneath the achievements view would have highlighted a comment.

Comment: The second part has been reported: [You can tap through the X meant to close the achievements view](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234175/). The first one seems to be new. For completeness, perhaps you could add the version of the app  and of the Android you are running?

Comment: Do you mean achievements view? It happens with achievement view for me on android 4.4.4 on moto g, v. 1.0.51

Comment: @CRags achievements, yes.

Comment: @Behaviour added, just saw the east of your comment.